# Photoshop edit text problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, font-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I identify what font was used in a Photoshop layer when the font is not installed on my computer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3771/how-can-i-identify-what-font-was-used-in-a-photoshop-layer-when-the-font-is-not-i)

I have a psd file and i want to edit a text from a particular layer.
The problem is this message "the following fonts are missing for text layer..." warning 
that a substitution will occur. What can i do about it? How can i edit the text? My initial problem was to find out what font was used there with photoshop. Is there another way?(besides
the edit text tool)

I use photoshop cs3 extended (version 10). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The original font must be on your computer for you to edit it—there is unfortunately no other way. Assuming all the licensing is in order, you can copy the relevant font files from the original computer to yours. Alternatively, you can use a similar font that you already have. Fortunately, the substitution doesn’t happen until *after* you edit the text layer.

Answer (score 1):

You have all to resolve yourself this problem.

You say: [The problem is this message "the following fonts are missing for text layer..."]

Sorry, this is the solution, not the problem. Take note or "Ctrl-c/Ctrl-v" the missing fonts in this error message.
Google it, download it, and install the missing fonts in your windows system. Better reboot after that, and Photoshop should open without errors the original file with the correct font, and editable layer.

Hope this helps.